# a bit fewer - is the phrase correct?

Tags: word-usage

I have a sharp dispute with my friend regarding English. It is about correct and accurate translation of the following German sentence into English:

> *Er machte ein bisschen weniger Fehler.*

My translations are as follows:

> 1. He made slightly fewer mistakes.
> 2. He made somewhat fewer mistakes.
> 3. He made a couple fewer mistakes.

I have only a few doubts about the third sentence.

Me friend thinks that the following translation is correct too:

> 4. He made a bit fewer mistakes.

I think this is bad English. In my opinion you can always say in English "a bit more" but never "a bit few". 
I didn't find any example frase wity "a bit fewer" in British or American dictionary.

My friend found examples from New York Times on the following website: https://ludwig.guru/s/a+bit+fewer

> The number of potholes is reportedly on par with, or a bit fewer than, those caused by the brutal weather of the previous two winters. (New York Times)
>
> There are a bit fewer people flying because of scare-mongering that its dangerous to fly, that you're going to get held up at the airport for a long time. (New York Times)

He thinks the New York Times authority ends the discussion.

I would love to hear your opinion on this subject.

Comment: I'm actually unsure about what that third one should be. Both "a couple less" and "a couple fewer" sound wrong to me. Same for "a bit less" and "a bit fewer".

Comment: The idiomatic standard for such contexts is ***a bit / a few less***. To "de-emphasize" ***fewer***, we commonly use terms like ***rather*** or ***somewhat***, not ***a bit*** - probably partly because ***a bit*** is relatively informal compared to ***fewer*** (and although *syntactically*, [***a few fewer***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+few+fewer+of%22) is fine, we'd tend to avoid it because it sounds a bit "clunky").